# OAuth access_token refresh techniques

Tags: reactjs, oauth, redux, access-token, refresh-token

I'm implementing OAuth in my React / Redux ( Or other Flux based state management ) application, And i'm struggling to find good information on "pro's vs cons" of various access_token extension methods.

---

**1) Intercept 401 responses**

One option would be to intercept API requests (E.g using "fetch-intercept" package) and detect any 401 HTTP code responses.

In the case we 401 we build logic to retrieve a new access_token, and then replay the previous request.

- Replay could be handled via dispatching an INVALID_TOKEN action in the 401 handler, catching these through middle-ware, Which would then replay the action before the INVALID_TOKEN action occurred.

*Pros*

- Full visibility of auth failure related actions are visible ( Therefore we could replay auth related bugs using time travel debugging )

---

**2) Detecting out of date access_token at time of API call**

Another method would be at the time of sending any request, decode our access_token and check if we need to refresh it soon ( And if so do so ).

Again some sort of middle-ware would be the best option for this solution. We could intercept all actions and before dispatching it first check we have a valid access_token.

*Pros*

- Doesn't need to hit the server just to receive a 401 response we could have instead preempted it

*Cons*

- More complicated logic to queue the requests whilst we're refreshing a token, before finally replaying them once it's been correctly refreshed

---

**3) Polling method**

Upon login, see how long it is until the token expires and set a timeout to refresh the access_token just before then

*Pros*

- *Simplest option ( Especially when retrofitting an app with lost of existing request logic )*

---

Any additional options or pro's vs cons for each method would be appreciated, so perhaps I can create an exhaustive list here for those starting out